# When clicking on on the LI then automatically click on input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click on li, I want input radio to be clicked.

However, I am getting an error from conole log saying:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How to fix this?

Here the html code:

```
    <ul class="Method">
        <li class="shipping_today active">
           <label> Label 1 </label>
            <input value="shipping_today"  name="shipping" type="radio" />
        </li>
        <li class="shipping_next_month">
            <label> Label 2 </label>
            <input value="shipping_next_month"  name="shipping" type="radio" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".Method li").click(function() { 
    var thisLi = $(this);
    var radio = $(this).find("input:radio");

    if (radio.val() == "shipping_today") {
        $(".Method li").eq(1).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }

    if (radio.val() == "shipping_next_month") {
        $(".Method li").eq(-2).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }

    radio.click(); //problem here...
});
```

Is my jQuery code good? what can be improved?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's an infinite loop, because the `click` event you trigger on the radio button [bubbles up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.bubbles) to the `<li>` element and causes your handler to run recursively.

One solution would be to only relay the `click` event if its doesn't come from the radio button itself:

```
$(".Method li").click(function(event) {
    var thisLi = $(this);
    var radio = $(this).find("input:radio");

    // [...]

    if (radio[0] !== event.target) {
        radio.click();
    }
});
```

If you only want to check the radio button, however, relaying the event is not necessary. You can use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
radio.prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent event bubbling, you can use stopPropagation():

```
$(".Method li").click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    ...
});
```

Comment: That won't work in our case, though, because the event bubbles *from* the radio button *up to* the list item. You would have to bind that handler to `$(".Method li input:radio")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs tweaks, try this:

```
$(".Method li").click(function() { 

    var thisLi = $(this);
    var radio = $(this).find("input:radio");

    if (radio.val() == "shipping_today") {
        $(".Method li").eq(1).removeClass("active"); 
        thisLi.addClass("active"); 

        radio.attr("checked", true);
    }

    else if (radio.val() == "shipping_next_month") {
        $(".Method li").eq(0).removeClass("active"); 
        thisLi.addClass("active");

        radio.attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

You can place radio.attr() only once outside of condition if all LI tags contain radio buttons.